# How *exactly* does rust look up modules?

Tags: rust, module

What is the exact set of rules that rust uses to look up a module from a file?

Every explanation I have found online about modules says, "this is the purpose of modules, here is an example of one, ..." None give the complete, comprehensive, 100% accurate explanation for *how rust looks up modules*. Even the rust [reference](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/items/modules.html) doesn't tell you whether both the crate root and the importing file need to declare `mod`! There is no simple ruleset I can use to tell whether it will work.

I'm looking for something *I* can follow, like:

1. Rust looks at the name, parsing `::` like `subdir::subdir::name`
2. Rust looks to see if there is a file `name.rs` in the same directory and `name/mod.rs`
3. There is not allowed to be both a `name.rs` and a `name/mod.rs`.
4. Then, Rust...???

Comment: I don't think there's a step 4 here. It's either `name/mod.rs` or `name.rs`, excepting the top level where `crate` can refer to `lib.rs`.

Comment: That can't be right. What about `crate::` delcarations? Also, what about the correspondence between `a::b::c` and `a/b/c.rs`? Does that work? The reference seems to imply a correspondence between these path types, but doesn't explicitly say that it will be looked up from a particular file (or which files!).

Comment: `a::b::c` is either `a/b/c.rs` or `a/b/c/mod.rs`. `crate` generally refers to `lib.rs` at the top level of the crate, though really it's all about what `mod` declarations are made along the way, starting with `mod a` being done somewhere. If you follow that trail you'll know where you're going. I believe Rust follows that chain as well, however it's defined.

Comment: Rust does not look for files when encountering a path `subdir::subdir::name`, it only looks for files when there is a `mod name;` (where the logic follows #2 and #3).

Comment: But that's the confusing thing! I believe `crate` doesn't always refer to lib.rs or main.rs. For example, if you specify multiple binaries, doesn't it refer to the particular binary being compiled (so it depends on the binary?) and crate can refer to different things in the same directory tree.

Comment: You find it confusing that `crate` would refer to the crate within which the source code resides?

Comment: @kmdreko It might not be obvious to the OP that what most people think of as crate is in fact a "package" (crates.io should be packages.io), and that each binary constitutes a different _crate_ within the package. So yes, without that context, it'd be confusing.

Comment: @user4815162342 I did think "crate" meant "the thing I see on crates.io". In fact I use the word "crate" to mean that, as in "the serde_json crate" or "the actix crate"

Comment: In the shipping analogy, I think of a crate containing multiple packages so that's backward haha

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is best explained starting from inline modules. Modules are arranged into a hierarchy from the crate root. Every crate, after some desugaring, looks something like this:

```rust
// root

pub mod a {
    pub mod b {
        pub const X: u8 = 1;
    }
}

mod foo {
    
}
```

Referring to an item in the tree is pretty simple:

- `::` goes "down" a level
- `super::` goes "up" a level
- `crate::` goes to the root level

Examples for referring to `X`:

- `a::b::X` from the crate root
- `crate::a::b::X` from anywhere in the crate
- `super::a::b::X` from within module `foo`
- `b::X` from within module `a`

`mod foo;` is really just syntax sugar for either of the following:

```rust
#[path = "foo.rs"]
mod foo;
// or
#[path = "foo/mod.rs"]
mod foo;
```

Which further desugar to:

```rust
mod foo {
    include!("foo.rs");
}
// or
mod foo {
    include!("foo/mod.rs");
}
```

If `foo.rs` (or `foo/mod.rs`) contains a `mod bar;` then the whole tree would look like:

```rust
mod foo {
    mod bar {
        // contents of `bar.rs` (or `foo/bar/mod.rs`)
    }

    // remaining contents of `foo.rs`
}
```

Please note that the usage of `mod.rs`, while still supported, is discouraged. Instead, it's recommended to use `foo.rs` for `crate::foo` and place any submodules of `foo` in the `foo/` directory.

If both `src/foo/mod.rs` and `src/foo.rs` exist, the compiler will throw the following error:

```
error[E0761]: file for module `foo` found at both "src\foo.rs" and "src\foo\mod.rs"
 --> src\main.rs:1:1
  |
1 | mod foo;
  | ^^^^^^^^
  |
  = help: delete or rename one of them to remove the ambiguity
```

`crate::` just always corresponds to the root module of the crate being compiled at the time. If your crate is sufficiently complex or doesn't follow convention, then certain `crate::...` item paths can refer to different things in different files. But confusion is easily avoidable by following conventions.

Here's the list of conventions I would use to avoid confusion:

- avoid `#[path]` attributes
- always use `src/foo.rs` instead of `src/foo/mod.rs`
- if you have multiple root modules (for instance a library and binary crate), they should all live directly in `src`
- minimize fancy configuration in `Cargo.toml`, use defaults where possible

Comment: This is great. If I'm always to stick to convention, is there a clear explanation for what the convention is (rules I can follow to always know this is good enough to follow)?

Comment: (1) What exact ruleset determines "root being compiled at the time". (2) You say "is really just syntax sugar for either of the following", and give multiple examples. How do you determine *which* of these it will desugar to?

Comment: @Test I've edited the question to address your comments